# Open share dialog in both web and mobile using angular 4-5-6

Tags: angular5

I want to share  my jokes status etc using angular 5 web.

When I click on share button from particular jokes it will shows me share dialog if user open website from mobile .

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Develop some code for it and ask your doubts...

Comment: any plugins available??